# React Native setState can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have tab view. Each tab render its own view. In those view I am setting `setState` in `componentDidMount`. When I am switching my tab so frequently then its give the warning. After reading some post what I understand is I have abort the request when I am leaving the view in `componentWillUnmount`. But I am not getting any Idea how can I get it done.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let res = await this.props.dispatch(getUserList());
    if(res.userList != undefined ){
      // to find unique roles...
      let data, unique = [];
      data =[...res.userList.data];
      unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.attributes.role))];
      await this.props.dispatch(uniqueData(unique, data));

      let groupList, listType, contactList;
      let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
      userList = [...this.props.directory.userList];
      this.setState({
        groupListData: ds.cloneWithRows(userList || []),
        selectedRole: 'All Contacts',
        isReady: true
      });
    }
    else{
      this.setState({ isReady: true });
    }

  }
```

Comment: am not sure if react native supports the redux or not, if yes then set a loading prop and do not  init the api call if its already loading...or data is already present

Comment: Yes it does support redux.